# converting C++ code to F#( function )

Tags: f#

Can anyone convert this C++ code to f#?

```
int power(int a,int b)
{
  if(b==1)
  {
     return a;
  } 
  else 
      return a*power(a,b-1);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did it work? How *didn't* it work (often more important to know)?

Comment: Converting this should be simple - show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most straight forward translation from the C++ version (although I prefer Aluan's match);

```
let rec power a b =
    if b = 1 then a
    else a * power a (b-1)
```

Another - almost cheating - option would be;

```
let power a b = a ** b
```

Comment: "Cheating" option will not work as `**` operator is not defined for integral types.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

```
let rec power x y =
    match y with
    | 1 -> x
    | _ -> x * power x (y-1)
```

which is long form for the terser and presumably more idiomatic equivalent

```
let rec power x = function 1 -> x | y -> x * power x (y-1)
```

Comment: Pattern matching, as in this example, would be most idiomatic, I would say.

Comment: Even shorter: `let rec power x = function 1 -> x | y -> x * power x (y-1)`

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat, I'll add `let rec power x = function 1 -> x | y -> x * power x (y-1)` as a shorthand.